# Declaration of for loop with double greater than operator

Tags: c++

I came across this line of code in a reseach paper for "[Efficient Integral Image Computation on the GPU](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224167113_Efficient_Integral_Image_Computation_on_the_GPU)":

```
for (int d = n>>1; d>0; d>>=1){...}
```

(int) n is an input variable.

I am familiar with for-loops and c++ in general. So I just could figure out the parts `n>>1` and `d>>=1`. I havent seen this before. Could someone provide a short explanation?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to google "C++ operators"? It's bound to give you a list with explanation to every operator.

Comment: Its a bit shifting operator.

Comment: okay, know I see what it is. I havent seen a shifting operator in a for loop head. That might be my problem. It this common practice or seldom used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>>` is the bitwise operator for right shift.

> Binary Right Shift Operator. The left operands value is moved right by
>   the number of bits specified by the right operand.

[Source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bitwise_operators.htm)

So this:

```
n >> 1
```

will move all the bits of `n` 1 place to the right.

> `>>=` is a right shift assignment
>   operator. It takes that value stored in i and shifts all it's bits to
>   the right 1 place (with the leftmost bit being set to 0)

As a reuslt, this:

```
d >>= 1
```

is equivalent to this:

```
d = d >> 1;
```